# MySQL Procedure Insert only if not exists

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL Stored Procedures and I want to insert some rows from a table's database to another table's database through a stored procedure. More specifically from database "new_schema", table "Routers" and field "mac_address" to database "data_warehouse2", table "dim_cpe" and field "mac_address".

This is the code I used in the first insertion, that worked perfectly.

```
insert into data_warehouse2.dim_cpe (data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address, data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.ssid)
(select new_schema.Routers.mac_address, new_schema.Routers.ssid from new_schema.Routers, data_warehouse2.dim_cpe);
```

Now I have more rows in the table "Routers" to be inserted into "dim_cpe" but, since there are rows already there, I want just to insert the new ones.

As seen in other posts, I tried a where clause:

```
where new_schema.device_info.mac_address != data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address
```

and a:

```
on duplicate key update new_schema.Routers.mac_address = data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address"
```

Both didn't work. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the table structure?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/9wstkpm47/
http://postimg.org/image/9oxfooqid/

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the source table out of the from clause, and use a not exists clause instead:

```
where not exists
(select mac_address from dim_cpe mac_address = new_schema.Routers.mac_address
and ssid = new_schema.Routers.ssid)
```

Or you could left join and check whether the fields from dim_cpe are null:

```
insert into data_warehouse2.dim_cpe
(data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address, data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.ssid)
(select new_schema.Routers.mac_address, new_schema.Routers.ssid
from new_schema.Routers
  left join data_warehouse2.dim_cpe on
    new_schema.Routers.mac_address = data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address
    and new_schema.Routers.ssid = data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.ssid
where dim_cpe.mac_address is null and dim_cpe.ssid is null);
```

Edit to say this is a general SQL solution. I'm not sure if there's a better MySql-specific approach to this.

Edit to show your query:

```
insert into data_warehouse2.dim_cpe (mac_address, ssid)
select new_schema.Routers.mac_address, new_schema.Routers.ssid
from new_schema.Routers where not exists
    (select data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address from data_warehouse2.dim_cpe
    where data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address = new_schema.Routers.mac_address
       and data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.ssid = new_schema.Routers.ssid);
```

Comment: It would look like this?
insert into data_warehouse2.dim_cpe (data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.mac_address, data_warehouse2.dim_cpe.ssid)
select new_schema.Routers.mac_address, new_schema.Routers.ssid from data_warehouse2.dim_cpe where not exists
(select dim_cpe.mac_address from data_warehouse2.dim_cpe where mac_address = new_schema.Routers.mac_address and ssid = new_schema.Routers.ssid);

Comment: Not quite, you should be selecting from new_schema.Routers rather than data_warehouse2.dim_cpe. I've edited my post to show you.

Comment: Ok, worked with the "where not exists" clause. Thanks a lot!